# Is i,j = 1 really misleading?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

There is a common argument about multiple variable initialisation in a one liner, that is :

> Consider for example int i, j = 1; which might lead some people to mistakingly believe both variables are being initialized

We could argue that someone should know enough the syntax of his language to not mistaken about that. Another argument could be as developers we learn so many languages we can make mistakes between the specificities between languages.

However for that very specific case I'm wondering the following does it even exists a language where the very syntax *i, j=1* initialize both variable ?

If not that argument then doesn't apply.

Comment: None of the languages listed at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Variables appear to have this functionality.

Comment: If your language is sane, the potential confusion is harmless because accessing an uninitialized variable triggers a compiler error.

Comment: @CodesInChaos are you saying C isn't sane?

Comment: Re, "someone should know enough of the syntax...",  The developer who will be asked to read, and maybe modify your code won't be allowed to choose which language it is written in.

Comment: @jameslarge I agree, I'm ask for the curiosity, I pretty much write this kind of statement once in a year.

Comment: To voters, I wasn't sure if this was on the scope of the site, but since i=I'am asking that is the syntax exists in others language, I fail to see where I'm asking a book or invite opinion. I don't mind if it end up closed, but close it for the good reason please.

Comment: Just because a language allows something doesn't mean you aren't causing the humans needless pain. The only place this code is called for is during quizzes designed to punish those who haven't memorized the language specification. I always failed these types of questions. Bleh.

Comment: That's almost as annoying as `int * x, y;`

Comment: @Baldrickk with `-Wall -Werror` it _will_ trigger a compiler error even in C – in any decent modern compiler, unless it can't prove the variable is actually used before being assigned another value.

Comment: In Visual Basic 6 `Dim Apple, Orange, Pear as Fruit` is a legal declaration. Suppose you do not know VB. Is your first impression that `Apple` is of type `Fruit`?  It is not. Remember, languages are often read by people who are not experts in that language; if you are an expert, use the language wisely to communicate your intentions clearly even to non-experts. I never use multiple initializations in any language.

Comment: Similarly: consider `var x = 1, y = 1.5;`  Is this the same as `int x = 1; double y = 1.5;` or is it the same as `double x = 1, y = 1.5;`?  When we added `var` to C# 3.0 I did a poll and discovered that about half the people believed that the first was "obviously" correct and the other half believed the other one was "obviously" correct, and so we made it illegal.  A feature that misleads fully half the population is a bad feature.

Comment: @leftaroundabout fair enough, you should always use those flags.  I try to avoid doing this in my code anyway.  But this is still at the compiler, not the language specification.  It's a warning because something bad might be happening, not because the specification outlaws it (though it does state that it is UB)

Comment: @CandiedOrange I just asked for the curiosity, though my code quality can't be said ot be high, I write this kind of statement once in a year. And don't forget the questions about where you can put the brackets for array.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think not, but that's not the point. The point is that `i, j = 0` is very easily mistaken for `i = j = 0`, which *does* initialize both. Clarity is the most important requirement on source code next to correctness, and the fact that this question even arises proves that the clarity is suboptimal.

Comment: I also would argue that if such a statement does _not_ initialize both statements, why does it even exist?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch depends on language. This is frequently done in JavaScript because of declaration hoisting: it is considered best practice by many to declare variables at the top of the scope in which they are available even if you don't initialize them until the spot they're used in the code. Almost all code transformation tools output in this fashion.

Comment: I suppose it's one thing if a code output tool did this, since that is supposed to be trusted.  However, for humans I would recommend against it combining declaration and initialization of the last element only on one line.  It just looks like a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @JaredSmith Besides Maple, I can't think of a language where this is currently desired, even C now prefers closer to scope (like C++ and most other languages with half decent static compilers) because it gives the benefit of stopping potential bugs and allows the compiler to decide what to do with the variable as long as the functionality doesn't change, potentially allowing better optimizations given that you could get away with less registers.

Comment: @snb: If I were designing a language, I'd have a declaration syntax for named captured values which would be designed to be declared very close to use, but which would allow reuse of names provided that if any code between a particular declaration and use would pass through another declaration, *every* such code path must do so, thus ensuring that it would always be clear where values came from.

Comment: Regardless of the language, one should ask "What is the *benefit* of writing `int i, j=1` versus `int i; int j = 1` (or even better, separate lines)?"

Comment: If I continue what you said Kilian, we shouldn't also write `i = j = 0` because we could mistake it for the other. Personnaly I rarely see `i,j=0`, and even less `i = j =0`.

Comment: @chepner I didn't asks about the benefits because it's just too opinion biaised, so I preferred focused on the fact, which is that every language agree on that point and do the same with the same syntax.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I'm inclined to agree. That said, your functions should be small enough that variable hoisting doesn't impact code quality anyway, so...

Comment: @chepner or at least `int j=1, i`. Or perhaps `int i=0, j=1`.

Comment: @snb no one ever said it was desired. But unlike C and C++ JavaScript does not have block scoping, only function scoping (pre ES6). So declaring at the point of usage is actually a source of error, because the declaration gets hoisted under the hood to the top of the function body. Again, not desired, but you make the best of what you're stuck with. On a side note, cramming multiple things on one line like that is not necessarily what I'd call good practice.

Comment: @JaredSmith  Same thing in python and matlab, yet you don't see those languages advocating what you suggest.

Comment: I would argue that clarity is more important than correctness. I can fix incorrect. I don't know what to do with unclear.

Comment: @snb look, no block scope sucks in any language. But best practices are defined by the goal you are trying accomplish. Given how many times dupe questions that boil down to a bug based on lack of block scoping get asked in the JS tag on SO, it's a real problem for other algol-descendant language users who come to JS and get their expectation ("I saw a curly brace, therefor an inner-scope") violated. Python uses entirely different syntax (I am unfamiliar with matlab syntax).

Comment: @JaredSmith Both are function blocked scoped, what I'm saying is that your argument with Javascript doesn't apply purely on the blocked scope question, as these two other languages don't have the same convention despite having variables only scoped to function, the only difference is that javascript looks a lot more like C than matlab or python.  The real issue is people using the same name for outer-scope things as inner scope variables, which is confusing even in languages like C.  That is the issue that needs to be stopped, not close to context variable declarations.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can argue for either side:

- Kontra `i, j = 0`:
  Mathematicians do use this to mean that both `i` and `j` are supposed to be zero.
- Pro `i, j = 0`:
  It's a simple matter of knowing the precedence of your operators. And if you are doubtful about their precedence, now is the time to look it up.

  It's the same reason why we write stuff like `a.b += c[i]*d[i];` without the parentheses. Of course this is equivalent to `(a.b) += ((c[i])*(d[i]));`, but programmers can be expected to know the precedence of the most used operators by heart, and be able to look up the precedence of operators when they are not sure. Thus, parentheses are generally considered useless clutter unless they force a different evaluation order than the operator precedence would prescribe.

  Of course, there are exceptions. The precedence of `<<` and `+` is generally considered ambiguous enough to warant parentheses in either case. But that is the exception that proves the rule.

I, for one, would fall more onto the Pro side, but I'm prepared to stick to any styleguide that forbids such declarations. It's just not a matter worth fighting over.

Comment: I note that `int i, j = 0;` has no *operators* in it. The only *expression* in that *statement* is `0` and therefore *operator precedence* does not come into it. The parser does not treat `,` as the comma operator or `=` as the assignment operator; rather, these are grammatical parts of the declaration statement.

Comment: @EricLippert As far as precedence rules are concerned, that difference is irrelevant: Any C-style language I know uses the same precedences in a declaration as in other expressions. Anything else would invite desaster.

Comment: `but programmers can be expected to know the precedence of the most used operators by heart`, you say. In the example you give, I'm not sure most (average) programmers conceive of the member access operator or the array index operator as being operators in the mathematical sense at all, but instead think of them more as natural language nouns and the multiplication operator as the verb. That's why `int i, j, k = 0;` is such a fiendish construct, because it presents as the natural language analog of "int variables i, j, and k, are declared and shall be set to 0"!

Comment: @Steve How you remember the precedence rules as a programmer, is fully up to you. If it helps you to think of them as nouns of the language, do it. However, in that case you will run into problems when you see stuff like `*a[i]`, I don't think you can sufficiently parse that with the "nouns" analogy. As for `int i, j, k = 0;`, that could mean anything if you don't look up the rules: A third interpretation would be to declare `int i`, then evaluate `j` and finally assign `k = 0`. Unless you know the syntax of your language, you cannot parse such constructs. It's your problem if you do anyway.

Comment: @cmaster, I wasn't expressing my specific memorisation strategy haha. I'm not a C programmer so my familiarity with operator precedence in C is second-rate. But what I noted when I looked at your example is that I didn't even think of the multiplication operator as having a relative precedence to the array index operator. That is, I didn't read `a[i]` as an index operator applied to `a`, but rather read both together as an irreducible syntactic element specifying the operand of the multiplication operator, and thus I wasn't even prompted to evaluate the precedence. (1/2)

Comment: I think this ties into Eric's evidence, that C is at times so subtle that a person can think they know what they're looking at and have no uneasiness that would cause them to check their understanding, and yet be wrong. And it's not simply the problem of the programmer, but also the problem for langauge designers to avoid such subtleties, hence why declaring a comma-separated mixture of initialised and uninitialised variables, is such an uncommon idiom that it should probably be invalid syntax and require the writer to be more explicit. (2/2)